# IIS in load balancing, how to manage upload folder?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, load-balancing

I work in a ASP.NET MVC application and it will be deployed in a IIS with material load balancing.

My application allows to upload image and read image, but I don't know how to manage the upload directory because there is a load balancing infrastrucutre behind IIS and we should not stock files in the server directly.

I had the idea to use a virtual directory in IIS accessible by the two servers, and physicaly it's a folder in the network. But for now I didn't find the way to use the path of this virtual directory in my application.

Do you think if it's a good way or if there is a better way to resolve that ? And in the case of my solution is possible, how can I use the virtual directory in my app ?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't asp-classic.

Comment: You're right, I changed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common practice would be to use a File server. If part of domain, use same domain account to grant access to the folder. What you really need to take care of in your code is unique file names when its about upload in  load balanced environment, rest depends a lot on your infrastructure, but yes, a file server/share is the way to go.

Comment: So, you conform thant I need to use a virtual directory in IIS pointing to a directory in a file server ? For files names I use a generated name with guid

Comment: Not Virtual directory, a network share. Virtual directories are used to abstract directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

So I created a virtual dir. in IIS on both servers, the virtual dir. point somewhere in a file server accessible by the both servers, and my problem is resolved